# MSSQL High Availability Advice Required

Tags: sql-server, cluster, failover

I'm looking to implement a high availability SQL installation using MSSQL2012 or 2014 and there is 1 part of this I'm not sure about.

I plan to have a SQL cluster at site a, and a secondary SQL cluster at site B. The end users run the application externally and connect using external DNS. We have no control of client computers.

What would be the best way to fail over from site a, to site B immediately, considering that DNS takes several hours to propagate?

Many thanks.

Comment: You don't mention which SQL product you wish to use, if this was an MSSQL solution you could simply expose the Cluster VIP and allow it to load-balance itself - if it's another product the answer will vary with that choice.

Comment: Hi, apologies it would be MSSQL 2012 or 2014

Comment: In that case just setup the cluster as normal and expose the server's IPs and the cluster object IP and point clients to them.

Comment: But the VIP for the cluster will change as part of the failover? We also do not have access to the clients to change the ip/dns name. Sorry if I misunderstood your response